# Indentation in emacs for html with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, emacs, formatting, indentation

Here is roughly the kind of code that I have.

```
<body>
<p>
...
</p>

<script>
function func()
{
...
for(...)
{
...
}
}
</script>

<p> ... </p>

</body>
```

HTML by itself indents properly, but when I put in the javascript everything screws up.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the multiple modes:

- https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes
- http://wikemacs.org/wiki/JavaScript#Mix_html_and_Javascript
- https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode
- https://github.com/vspinu/polymode
- https://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode

Their goal is to have more than one mode at the same time in the same buffer, specially html and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is have blank lines in between my script tags and then switch over to javascript mode. The html would look like this with the blank line padding

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   //some javascript

</script>
```

That seems to allow correct coloring and indenting. I also like to use [js3-mode](https://github.com/thomblake/js3-mode) personally as it adds a bit more functionality than emacs' default javascript styling.